# Way to handle two-dimensional conditions when creating objects?

Tags: java

I have two variables, `foo` and `bar`, that determine which kind of object I need to create. At the moment, both of these can hold two different values, and the objects are created as such:

```
Result createResult(int foo, int bar) {
    if(foo == 0) {
        if(bar == 0) return new FirstResult();
        if(bar == 1) return new SecondResult();
    }else if(foo == 1) {
        if(bar == 0) return new ThirdResult();
        if(bar == 1) return new FourthResult();
    }
    return null;
}

// Common interface for all the objects
interface Result {

}
```

This work for just these four types, but what if there's more types? How should the object creation be handled so that it would be more efficient?

Comment: I would suggest an `enum` and switch-case.

Comment: what you are describing is a use-case for Factory Pattern.

Comment: Could you be a bit more concrete about your use case? The solution depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @dumb_terminal Could you elaborate? I'm familiar with the pattern, but wouldn't that just move the conditionals to a different place?

Comment: @Hugo All the classes would be implementing the same interface, providing different functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The if/else pattern should be very efficient up to a considerable size. However if things get really huge this changes and also readability suffers. I suggest a HashMap-Lookup for the correct constructor for faster result determination. This requires that you create a class that can be used as a key in a `HashMap`:

```
class CreationParams {
    private final int foo;
    private final int bar;

    CreationParams(final int foo, final int bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    // make sure to implement hashCode & equals so this class can be efficiently used in a Map
}
```

As already mentioned in the comment above, you absolutely need to implement `hashCode` and `equals`. If you do not implement `equals` or `hashCode` it will not work as the hashmap lookup will fail if the key is not the same (even if equal).

Now you can easily map a combination of parameters to a constructor and lookup the result. Consider this example:

```
class ResultFactory {
    private static final Map<CreationParams, Supplier<Result>> factories = createFactoryMap();

    private static Map<CreationParams, Supplier<Result>> createFactoryMap() {
        final Map<CreationParams, Supplier<Result>> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put(new CreationParams(0, 0), FirstResult::new);
        result.put(new CreationParams(0, 1), SecondResult::new);
        // ...
        return result;
    }

    Result createResult(int foo, int bar) {
        return factories.get(new CreationParams(foo, bar)).get();
    }
}
```

The point is that all your constructors (well delegators to the constructor) are now saved in the map `factories`. The lookup `factories.get(new CreationParams(foo, bar))` will be faster then lots of if statements as soon as some critical size is reached because it does not need to iterate all possible target objects, but only those with a colliding hash. Then you can immediately call `get` or in the real world you may want to check for null and throw some kind of exception in this case before.

## Without Java 8

If your are stuck on an older Java version your have basically two possible workarounds. In both cases you will need to create your own Supplier interface like this (well technically you don't need the interface for the reflection variant because it only requires a single implementing class that you could also use directly):

```
interface Supplier {
    Result get();
}
```

Then one way is to use reflection which needs less source code:

```
class ReflectionSupplier implements Supplier {
    final Class<? extends Result> clazz;

    ReflectionSupplier(final Class<? extends Result> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Result get() {
        try {
            return clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can add classes to the Map as follows:

```
result.put(new CreationParams(0, 0), new ReflectionSupplier(FirstResult.class));
```

The other alternative is to just use (anonymous) classes for each instance. The advantage is that there is a bunch of errors which can be compile time discovered (such as no default constructor available). The disadvantage is that this creates loads of lines. Just add to your map like this:

```
result.put(new CreationParams(0, 0), new Supplier() {
    @Override
    public Result get() {
        return new FirstResult();
    }
});
```

Comment: How would you do this without Java 8 features (i.e. without `::new`)?

Comment: @manabreak: I extended the answer on how to do it without Java 8.

Comment: Should ResultFactory.createResult() be static?

Comment: @yankee Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: Probably not, because making that method static will deprive you of the chance of using that factory as a dependency injected object.

Answer (score 1):

well lets try something chicky

```
private String [][] classNames = new String[][]{
    {"com.something.FirstResult", "com.something.SecondResult"},
    {"com.something.ThirdResult", "com.something.ThirdResult"}
};

Result createResult(int foo, int bar) {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(classNames[foo][bar]);
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

If the constructors had parameters may be something like ..

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.something.SomeClass");
Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class, Integer.class);
Object instance = constructor.newInstance("some string", 0);
```

Also as yankee suggested:

```
Class [] classes = new Class[]{FirstClass.class, SecondClass.class };
classes[0].newInstance()
```

would be another way to achieve similar to what I had in mind.

Comment: Why `Class.forName("com.something.SomeClass")` and not simply `com.something.SomeClass.class`?

Comment: both are correct.. I was just showing some way to do it. If he uses class names then may be the array can come of from another source like file or database lol.

Answer (score 1):

This may be overkill, but you could use a data structure to map a foo/bar pair to a `Class` instance, then call `newInstance()` on that instance to create your object.  Here's more or less how it would look using a two-dimensional array to store the `Class`es:

```
static Class[][] classes = new Class[][]{
   { FirstResult.class, SecondResult.class},
   { ThirdClass.class,FourthResult.class}
}

Result createResult(int foo, int bar){
    if (foo < 0 || foo >= classes.length)
        return null;
    if (bar < 0 || bar >= classes[foo].length)
        Return null;
    Try {
        return classes[foo][bar].newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException ie) { 
        // Shouldn't happen
    } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
        // also shouldn't happen
     } 
}
```

This code is off the top of my head so I don't guarantee it will work as is, but it should give you the general idea...

Comment: Oops, @dumb_terminal got there ahead of me with more or less the same solution